# Find/Replace VBA code is not executing properly

Tags: vba, ms-word

For some odd reason, my code does **not** work in all instances. It does not catch every instance where there is only 1 space after a period. I was wondering if anyone knows why this may be. I went through every line and I can't figure out why it won't work. It's pretty basic of a code.

The goal behind this code:

1. period with 1 space goes to period with 2 spaces
2. period with 2 spaces stay the same
3. any double spaces in the document that do not follow a period are changed to 1 space.
4. Mr., Mrs., Miss., Ms. only have 1 space after them.

````
Sub Space_corrections()

' two spaces go to one space entire doc

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' One space after periods goes to two spaces

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ". "
        .Replacement.Text = ".  "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Three spaces after periods goes to two spaces

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".   "
        .Replacement.Text = ".  "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Two spaces after Mr. goes to one space

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Mr.  "
        .Replacement.Text = "Mr. "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

 ' Two spaces after Mrs. goes to one space

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Mrs.  "
        .Replacement.Text = "Mrs. "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

 ' Two spaces after Ms. goes to one space

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Ms.  "
        .Replacement.Text = "Ms. "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Two spaces after Miss. goes to one space

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Miss.  "
        .Replacement.Text = "Miss. "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


End Sub```


UPDATE/EDIT: 

I changed over to this code, but it does to change all of the instances. I am not sure what the cause is. 

There is no special font on them or anything. They are sentences that are contained by a list format, but every other instance that was changed was also contained in a list format. 
These are the instances that went unchanged:
**"shipped. According"
"materials. The"**

updated code: 
    Sub Space_corrections_123()

        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "(.)( {1,})"
            .Replacement.Text = "\1  "
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    End Sub
````

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the find and replace for the Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms/Dr/Professor etc by using a wildcard search

```
.findtext="([rs])(.  )"  
.replacementText="\1. "
```

Which will find any word ending in a r or s followed by a point and two spaces and replace with the found character plus point and one space.

You can also do a wildcard search to consolidate the replacement of . by to . two spaces using

```
.findtext="(.)( {1,})"  
.replacementText="\1  "
```

Comment: That's a rather unhelpful comment.  What exactly didn't work .  Can we tweak it further?  Have you considered you may be having issues because you have some non breaking spaces instead of ordinary spaces?

Comment: The OP is using *wildcards* in Word, not RegEx. The two are not equivalent.

Comment: @macropod the OP code repeatedly states '.MatchWildcards = False'.  Also, the codes I provided are perfectly valid Wildcards for Word.

Comment: My bad. That said, your first F/R expression is too broad in its scope, picking up any sentence ending in r or s and your second one would need to be executed before the first one.

Comment: It appears to not function when you have track edits on with "no mark up" selected. Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: I'm surprised you need to make that observation.  Can you not just turn off those features during the search and replace then turn them back on again afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "([ ^s]){2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "(. )"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([DM][irs]{1,3}.)[ ]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note the 'D' in '[DM]'. That allows you to find Dr., & Drs. as well (in case there's more than one). You can delete the 'D' if it's unnecessary.